# Crop and resize image - Is it possible to use <%= image_tag %> for setting a background-image?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, image-processing, crop

In this project users can upload an image to a post.
This image should be displayed with a fixed height and 100% width.

So the image has to be cropped depending on the image size of the upload.

I would like to use a CSS only solution like here http://jsfiddle.net/tx7sf/90/ 
where the image is integrated as a background-image in order to crop the image.

html:

```
<div class="thumb" style="background-image: url('http://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_ly7xjxn3QI1r62v9yo1_1280.png');"></div>
```

css:

```
.thumb {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 5px;
    border: 3px solid #c99;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Here comes my newbie question:

In the fiddle example above there is a fix URL for the image, but I have to use depending on the upload something like this:

```
<%= image_tag @post.image.url(:fullscreen), :class=> "imagearea", :id=> "img_prev" %>
```

Is it possible to use an image_tag like above for such an CSS background-image integration?

How could I do this?
Or does this make no sense at all?

Thank you so much for your help! Really appreciated!

**UPDATE:**

A little more specific:
I want to use this image inside a form which looks something like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for @post do |f| %>

 <%= image_tag @post.image.url(:fullscreen), :class=> "imagearea", :id=> "img_prev" %> 
   <div class="container"> 
              <h1> <%= f.text_area :title, 
                  :class => "imagefield", 
                  :rows => 1,
                  :placeholder => 'Enter your Title.',
                  :maxlength=>"48" %>
              </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="addpicture">
      <input href="#" id="post_image" name="post[image]" type='file'  onchange="readURL(this);" />
    </div>

<% end %>
```

Thanks again!

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you are asking but is it something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/S59EW/21/show/, this will keep the ratio while centering the image. (Can be different points to scale at like top, left, right, bottom)

Comment: @JoshPowell Yes, something like this, just with a fix height, not full screen.

Comment: Then all you need to do is change the height I it! :)

Comment: @JoshPowell Thanks, yes ;), but my real challenge is not the cropping, it's more the question how can I use an rails image_path instead of a fix URL. See the comments below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at `image_path`.

```
<div class="thumb" 
  style="background-image: url('<%= image_path(@post.image.url(:fullscreen) %>');"></div>
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html#method-i-image_path

Comment: Philip, thank you so much for your answer! I tried to implement it, and played around with it, but I can't make it work. I get an SyntaxError. Probably because of the form I am using? I added some more details above.

Comment: If I use ' <div class="thumb" 
        style="background-image: url(image_path(@post.image.url(:fullscreen)))">
      </div> ' , then the error is gone, but unfortunately the image is not shown.

Comment: Finally, I found a working solution: ' style="background-image: url(<%=@post.image.url%>)"> ' -- Thanks again for helping. Sorry again for asking this newbie questions.